# How do I check whether @ray.remote is using all available nodes?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ray

I have a computing-intensive script that uses Ray.io to assign the task to the two computing nodes. How do I know whether the nodes are in use or not, when assigning a function to `@ray.remote`?

The reason I ask is that I use CPU to run Inference via TensorFlow, time taken is around 200s, for the computing cluster described below (two GPU nodes with 16 GPU cores), it took around 190s, which I think it's unexpected. I expected the time taken should be much less than the CPU.

The notebook is available at: https://github.com/shivanraptor/object-detection/blob/main/Object%20Detection.ipynb

After `ray.init(address="auto")`, here is the output:

```
RayContext(dashboard_url='172.24.31.101:8265', python_version='3.8.5', ray_version='1.12.1', ray_commit='4863e33856b54ccf8add5cbe75e41558850a1b75', address_info={'node_ip_address': '172.24.31.101', 'raylet_ip_address': '172.24.31.101', 'redis_address': None, 'object_store_address': '/tmp/ray/session_2022-06-02_02-37-25_924604_37/sockets/plasma_store', 'raylet_socket_name': '/tmp/ray/session_2022-06-02_02-37-25_924604_37/sockets/raylet', 'webui_url': '172.24.31.101:8265', 'session_dir': '/tmp/ray/session_2022-06-02_02-37-25_924604_37', 'metrics_export_port': 56458, 'gcs_address': '172.24.31.101:6379', 'address': '172.24.31.101:6379', 'node_id': '5671f6d6e692cc0aa29ef688b5494d2f6cb7b5d56cdebbefaaba42ac'})
```

here is the output of `ray.nodes()`:

```
[{'NodeID': '5671f6d6e692cc0aa29ef688b5494d2f6cb7b5d56cdebbefaaba42ac',
  'Alive': True,
  'NodeManagerAddress': '172.24.31.101',
  'NodeManagerHostname': 'mgmt01',
  'NodeManagerPort': 39889,
  'ObjectManagerPort': 37609,
  'ObjectStoreSocketName': '/tmp/ray/session_2022-06-02_02-37-25_924604_37/sockets/plasma_store',
  'RayletSocketName': '/tmp/ray/session_2022-06-02_02-37-25_924604_37/sockets/raylet',
  'MetricsExportPort': 56458,
  'alive': True,
  'Resources': {'CPU': 4.0,
   'memory': 9791670683.0,
   'node:172.24.31.101': 1.0,
   'object_store_memory': 4895835340.0}},
 {'NodeID': '59496ae8c13baa067dd4e28bc95cdd1fe531e2314f7f0c5231ea94d2',
  'Alive': True,
  'NodeManagerAddress': '172.24.31.103',
  'NodeManagerHostname': 'gpu02',
  'NodeManagerPort': 36761,
  'ObjectManagerPort': 41267,
  'ObjectStoreSocketName': '/tmp/ray/session_2022-06-02_02-37-25_924604_37/sockets/plasma_store',
  'RayletSocketName': '/tmp/ray/session_2022-06-02_02-37-25_924604_37/sockets/raylet',
  'MetricsExportPort': 56304,
  'alive': True,
  'Resources': {'memory': 94294953984.0,
   'object_store_memory': 40412123136.0,
   'GPU': 4.0,
   'CPU': 40.0,
   'accelerator_type:G': 1.0,
   'node:172.24.31.103': 1.0}},
 {'NodeID': 'fbef77931bc3a5d75b862691ad52f504ae2676638a1f1fadc5125e4f',
  'Alive': True,
  'NodeManagerAddress': '172.24.31.105',
  'NodeManagerHostname': 'gpu01',
  'NodeManagerPort': 38411,
  'ObjectManagerPort': 44091,
  'ObjectStoreSocketName': '/tmp/ray/session_2022-06-02_02-37-25_924604_37/sockets/plasma_store',
  'RayletSocketName': '/tmp/ray/session_2022-06-02_02-37-25_924604_37/sockets/raylet',
  'MetricsExportPort': 60411,
  'alive': True,
  'Resources': {'object_store_memory': 40410541670.0,
   'accelerator_type:G': 1.0,
   'node:172.24.31.105': 1.0,
   'GPU': 4.0,
   'CPU': 40.0,
   'memory': 94291263898.0}}]
```

And the output of `ray.cluster_resources()`:

```
{'object_store_memory': 85718500146.0,
 'CPU': 84.0,
 'memory': 198377888565.0,
 'node:172.24.31.101': 1.0,
 'node:172.24.31.103': 1.0,
 'GPU': 8.0,
 'accelerator_type:G': 2.0,
 'node:172.24.31.105': 1.0}
```

p.s. It's weird that I cannot access the Ray dashboard (I can access it before). If I can access the dashboard, I probably can check the GPU usage over there.

**UPDATE**

The output of `ray status` (looks fine for me):

```
ray status
======== Autoscaler status: 2022-08-03 01:35:16.068521 ========
Node status
---------------------------------------------------------------
Healthy:
 1 node_fbef77931bc3a5d75b862691ad52f504ae2676638a1f1fadc5125e4f
 1 node_59496ae8c13baa067dd4e28bc95cdd1fe531e2314f7f0c5231ea94d2
 1 node_5671f6d6e692cc0aa29ef688b5494d2f6cb7b5d56cdebbefaaba42ac
Pending:
 (no pending nodes)
Recent failures:
 (no failures)

Resources
---------------------------------------------------------------
Usage:
 0.0/84.0 CPU
 0.0/8.0 GPU
 0.0/2.0 accelerator_type:G
 0.00/184.754 GiB memory
 0.00/79.832 GiB object_store_memory

Demands:
 (no resource demands)
```

Answer (score 0):

> p.s. It's weird that I cannot access the Ray dashboard (I can access it before). If I can access the dashboard, I probably can check the GPU usage over there.

If you're doing compute on a remote cluster, you likely can't access the dashboard due to a firewall between your browser and the head node.

You should be able to view the dashboard by doing `ray dashboard cluster.yaml` which will port-forward to your local laptop (thus you can access the dashboard at `localhost:8265`). (Note it's also possible to open up port 8265 on the firewall but you should be very careful when taking that approach as that http server is capable of remote code execution).

To ensure that your tasks are running on the cluster, you can also use a CLI tool like `ray status` which will show you the resource usage of your nodes, which should presumably add up to more than 1 machine. For example, this is what `ray status` shows on an empty 1 node cluster.

```
======== Autoscaler status: 2022-08-02 15:15:45.327862 ========
Node status
---------------------------------------------------------------
Healthy:
 1 node_1aeb97fdee5c982facc059e65f4489b0b23786e5b69e3a9878986962
Pending:
 (no pending nodes)
Recent failures:
 (no failures)

Resources
---------------------------------------------------------------
Usage:
 0.0/10.0 CPU
 0.00/38.127 GiB memory
 0.00/2.000 GiB object_store_memory

Demands:
 (no resource demands)
```

Comment: I added the `ray status` output; it looks fine for me. And all nodes are in the same local network. I can access the dashboard before. I want to ask where does the `cluster.yaml` locate?